# Plot Column w.r.t. Rows in A Matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a matrix `mat` like this below:

```
      V1    V2  
Helsinki   Bus  
Helsinki   Bus  
Helsinki  Tram  
  London Train  
  London   Bus  
  London Train  
...
```

What I want is to tabulate (using R) as in below:

```
      V1    V2   V3  
Helsinki   Bus    2  
Helsinki  Tram    1  
  London   Bus    1  
  London Train    2
```

And then plot a bar chart (using R) with my y-axis being column V2 such that they are coloured differently wrt V1.
For example, Bus needs to appear twice shaded differently(not clustered together) for Helsinki and London.

So, how do I do all of this?

EDIT:

I did get the tabulation done, but in plotting using ggplot. If i do this:

```
ggplot( data=mat, aes(x=V2, y=V3, fill=factor(V1)) )+
   geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", width=0.5) + coord_flip() + theme_minimal( base_size= 18 ) + ylab( "Mode of Transport" ) + xlab( "Frequency" ) + labs( fill= "City") + ggtitle( "Distribution of transportation modes" ) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))
```

I get a clustered bar plot. What should I do to get the variables in `V2` mentioned in all the cities `(V1)`?

Comment: To produce the table, you can use `dplyr::count(as.data.frame(mat), V1, V2)`

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot :) This dplyr package is really cool.

Comment: ask a new question, or better: do some research

Comment: I already updated the question and i believe asking is part of doing research !! Anyways, thanks for your input.

Comment: Perhaps you want `ggplot(DFcount, aes(x = Transport, y = n, fill = City)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks a lot for your help. I finally went with the stacked bar plot with ggplot option, like the one you showed before.

Answer (score 0):

The group_by function from the dplyr package could be useful

```
library(tidyverse)

group_by(df,V1,V2) %>%
  summarise(V3=n())
```

If I understand you correctly you want a barplot with the transportation methods clustered for each city (is that correct?). If so, you just change the aes() variables you have in you ggplot code.

```
aes(x=V1,y=V3,fill=V2)
```